# Return results as CompletableFutures completes?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, completable-future

I have a Spring Boot web application that takes a string as a GET request. The application then generates a list of text from the keyword in their own thread then returns a CompletableFuture.

Some threads may take 30 seconds to complete, other maybe less than a second.

Is it possible for the controller to return the result of each thread as they get completed to the calling client?

Comment: sounds like a streaming scenario, maybe you should take a look at reactive streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return `CompletableFuture<>` or a `List<CompletableFuture<>>` as they are finished.
Spring delivers a starter project `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'` that allows you to write non-blocking, reactive controllers.

So, provided that you have a list of `CompletableFuture<>` as the result of texts generations, your controller should look like this:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public Flux<String> getListReactively2(@RequestParam String keyword) {
        List<CompletableFuture<String>> completableFutures = getCompletableFutures(keyword);
        List<Mono<String>> monos = completableFutures.stream().map(Mono::fromFuture).toList();
        return Flux.fromIterable(monos).flatMap(Function.identity());
    }
```

The List of `CompletableFuture<>` is mapped to `Flux<String` which is the `spring-webflux` type that represents a Stream of objects that will be returned as the objects are delivered in the stream.

For more information, refer to spring webflux documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html